# Redirect HTTPS to HTTP for specifc page and its underlaying rsources

Tags: http, redirect, iis, https, url-rewriting

I have requirement in which i am redirecting any http request to https i.e http://test.amey.com/sitename to https://test.amey.com/sitename 
To achive this i am applying following rule in IIS url rewrite

```
<rule name="HTTP to HTTPS Redirect" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
   <match url="*" />
   <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
      <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/sitename" />
</rule>
```

The above rule works fine which redirects any http request to https.

But I have another requirement in which i want to redirect https request to http for certain pages and anything below it i.e
https://test.amey.com/sitename/reports/index - (where reports is controller name and index being action method)
to > 
http://test.amey.com/sitename/reports/index

Reports have more pages under this directory, so i want to apply rule anything under reports should redirect to http i.e

https://test.amey.com/sitename/reports/sales
to
http://test.amey.com/sitename/reports/sales

https://test.amey.com/sitename/reports/weeklysale to http://test.amey.com/sitename/reports/weeklysale

I have been looking for solution for sometime but can not figure anything out. Any help will be great advantage.

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution below always redirect user to Https but with exception of some pages defined in condition.

```
<rule name="Redirect to HTTPS">
              <match url="(.*)" />
              <conditions>
                <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="OFF"/>
                <add input="{URL}" pattern="(.*)reports" negate="true" />
              </conditions>
              <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{HTTP_URL}" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="false" />
     </rule>

     <rule name="Redirect to HTTP">
              <match url="(.*)" />
              <conditions>
                <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="ON"/>
                <!-- condition below will satisfy that any URL request containing Reports will redirect to http  --> 
                <add input="{URL}" pattern="(.*)reports" />
              </conditions>
              <action type="Redirect" url="http://{HTTP_HOST}{HTTP_URL}" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="false" />
     </rule>
```